# How to prove that a circle that contains chord $AB$ must contain $C$ or $D$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Fix $A=(0,0)$. Consider two points $C=(d_1\cos \alpha_1, d_1 \sin \alpha_1)$ and $D=(d_2\cos \alpha_2, -d_2 \sin \alpha_2)$. Findally, consider point $B$ at $(r\cos \theta , r\sin \theta)$ with $r>d_1+d_2$. The constraints are $0 \leq \alpha_1, \alpha_2 \leq \frac{\pi}{6}$, $-\alpha_2 \leq \theta \leq \alpha_1$. See below diagram:

[image]

How do I approve that **any circle** that contains $AB$ must contain either $C$ or $D$? I tried setting up an algebraic system but there is just too many variables. Is there a straightforward geometric argument?

Hints preferred over full answers.

Comment: Are all $B,C,D$ fixed as well?

Comment: @Andrei Yes. Just their value is parametrized on $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\theta, d_1, d_2, r$. So I need to show for fixed parameters, this holds.

Comment: To clarify, by "contains chord $AB$", you mean that the points $A$ and $B$ lie within the circle?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prove this for $r\geq 2\max(d_1,d_2)$ instead of $r>d_1+d_2$. This is sufficient for my needs but I still "feel" the right answer should be $r>d_1+d_2$ but I don't know how to prove it.

The thing that simplified my calculations is to rotate the coordinate system to make the chord parallel to the $x-$axis. So we get this new diagram in the new coordinate system:

[image]

Here, $\alpha_1', \alpha_2'$ are the new angles in the new coordinate system, between $[0, \frac{\pi}{3}]$ of the angles between $C,D$ and $AB$. Now any circle that contains $AB$ (now parallel to the new coordinate $x-$axis) will have center $(\frac{r}{2}, \Delta)$ for some $\Delta$ and radius $\frac{r^2}{4}+\Delta^2$ Now we calculate the two differences of distance from the center of that circle to both $C$ and $D$:

$$\delta_1 = (\frac{r}{2}-d_1\cos\alpha_1')^2+(\Delta - d_1\sin \alpha_1')^2 - \frac{r^2}{4}-\Delta^2$$
And

$$\delta_2 = (\frac{r}{2}-d_2\cos\alpha_2')^2+(\Delta + d_2\sin \alpha_2')^2 - \frac{r^2}{4}-\Delta^2$$

Simplifying, we get

$$\delta_1 = d_1(-2\Delta \sin \alpha_1'+d_1-r\cos \alpha_1')$$

and

$$\delta_2 = d_2(2\Delta \sin \alpha_2' + d_2-r\cos \alpha_2')$$

Now $d_1, d_2>0$, so if we show one of $(-2\Delta \sin \alpha_1'+d_1-r\cos \alpha_1'), (2\Delta \sin \alpha_2' + d_2-r\cos \alpha_2')$ must be negative, then we are done. We have

$$-2\Delta \sin \alpha_1'+d_1-r\cos \alpha_1' < -2\Delta \sin \alpha_1' $$
$$2\Delta \sin \alpha_2'+d_2-r\cos \alpha_2' < 2\Delta \sin \alpha_2'$$

Note that $0\leq \alpha_1' \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$ so $\sin(\alpha_1'), \sin(\alpha_2')\geq 0$. So if $\Delta$ is positive, $\delta_1$ must be negative, and if it is negative, $\delta_2$ must be negative. So at least one point must be inside the circle. $\Delta=0$ implies both points must lie inside (on border).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it holds for $r > d_1 + d_2$. Take $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(20,0)$. Place $C=(2,14)$ and $D=(-3,-4-\epsilon)$ and $D'=(-3,-4)$.

The circle passing through $A,B,D'$ contains $AB$ and misses both $D$ and $C$.

Here, $r=20$ which is larger than $d_1+d_2 = 19.2$.
Or have I misinterpreted a measurement/symbol here?

Comment: $C$ at $(2,14)$ must have $\alpha_1\approx 1.43$ radians, but the constraints require this angle to be not greater than $\frac{\pi}{6}\approx 0.52$ radians.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I missed the angle constraint. I will delete this answer